# SequenceFile doesn't work with GzipCodec without native-hadoop code

Tags: macos, hadoop

I am running Hadoop 1.2.1 on Mac OSX Mavericks.

When I tried to run mapreduce job, I have this message.

INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201406060001_0011_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SequenceFile doesn't work with GzipCodec without native-hadoop code!

How do I download / compile the required native codec?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question.  In the meantime, use BZip2 it compresses to smaller size (at a computational cost) and is splittable - it's generally the go-to compression for hadoop.

Comment: I will try your suggestion, modify all code to use bzip2 then. I am running example codes from Tom White's "Hadoop The Definitive Guide" https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/ .